# Where is the value OperatingSystem.OpenFileDescriptorCount gotten from?

Tags: file-io, jmx

I have a graph that is generated using JMX. It is something that comes from the graph tool that is used (dont know the name). I wonder where the value `OperatingSystem.OpenFileDescriptorCount` comes from. The reason I wonder is that there is a substantial difference between the value of this property and the output of lsof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder where the value OperatingSystem.OpenFileDescriptorCount comes from.

This information is generated by the JVM which monitors its file-descriptor opens and closes.

> I wonder is that there is a substantial difference between the value of this property and the output of lsof.

I would do some testing.  Probably depends on your architecture.

Looking at a couple of our production servers running CentOS Linux, and comparing `/proc/.../fd` to that counter shows that it is either spot on or very close.  `lsof` shows more information than file descriptors but it's number output looks to be very close as well.